# How do you write a tab (\t) inside a "@..." C# string?

Tags: c#, escaping

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# @“” how do i insert a tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748999/c-how-do-i-insert-a-tab)

I'm trying to just use the tab on my keyboard but the compiler interprets the tabs as spaces. Using `\t` won't work either, it will interpret it as `\t` literally. Is it not possible or am I missing something?

```
string str = @"\thi";
MessageBox.Show(str); // Shows "\thi"
```

Comment: Now you know the limit of `@` :-)

Comment: I cannot answer since this has been marked as a duplicate, but you could easily use an interpreted and verbatim string

`string str = $@"{"\t"}hi";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in VS2010 - if you copy to clipboard from a richtext application, and that content has a tab in it, I believe it will paste into the VS2010 editor as such.

(i consider this on the side of buggy and wouldn't be surprised if the behavior changes in the future)

Comment: It does answer my question though.

Comment: It might be woth noting that it's not the compiler that is inserting spaces, it's the default settings in the Visual Studio editor.  This can be turned off under tools->options

Answer (score 13):

Split your string and insert a `\t` where you want it?

```
var str = @"This is a" + "\t" + @"tab";
```

Comment: I kinda knew I can do that. My question is whether is possible to write it **in** and @"..." string.

Comment: I was all excited that my list of XML lines can look nicely indented in my C# code but now they can't :(

Comment: doesn't that go against the definition of what @ is for?  that said, in VS2010 - if you copy to clipboard from a richtext application, and that content has a tab in it, I believe it will paste into the VS2010 editor as such.

Comment: @Gabriel: you should post that as an answer. That actually works!!!
You can also copy and paste tabs from notepad. This way I can have my lines of text look nicely indented.

Comment: @Ahmet That's potentially asking for trouble when it comes to source control, other people's editors, preferences, etc.

Answer (score 7):

The whole point of a verbatim [string literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) is that escaping is turned off such that backslashes can be read as they are written. If you want escaping, then use a regular string literal (without the at symbol).

You could, of course, put a literal tab character (by pressing the tab key) within the string.

Answer (score 7):

Another option is to specify the tab as a parameter in string.Format:

```
string.Format(@"XX{0}XX", "\t"); // yields "XX    XX"
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using a [string literal](http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-literal).

Instead, just do this:

```
string str = "\thi";
MessageBox.Show(str);
```

Comment: You are using a string literal too. The difference is that you are not using a *verbatim* string literal.